# Windows desktop-based standalone RSS reader

Tags: windows, open-source, feed-reader

For privacy reasons, I am considering/looking for something like [Sharpreader](http://www.sharpreader.net/), but a bit more modern (with functionality a bit closer to modern RSS readers like [Inoreader](https://www.inoreader.com/)) to run on my Windows desktop PC and not rely on any cloud service to maintain my subscriptions, favourites, read status, etc.

Does such software exist?

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have started using [QuiteRSS](https://quiterss.org/). Current version is from July 2018, and it's still supported. Coming from RSSOwl, it has all the features of that program, plus more, but except one: [Automatic download of attachments](https://quiterss.org/en/forums/suggestions/suggest-new-filter-rule-automatic-download).

I also no longer require Java on my PC (RSSOwl did).

Answer (score 2):

You only have [RSS Bandit](http://rssbandit.org/) and [RSSOwl](http://www.rssowl.org/), but they are quite old fashioned. One of the best Windows based RSS reader was [FeedDemon](http://www.feeddemon.com/). You can still download it bit the developer stopped the development in June 2013.

You should consider opting for [Tiny Tiny RSS](https://tt-rss.org/), a brilliant and advanced self hosted open source platform.

Comment: FeedDemon is still great for me on Windows 7. I haven't tried using it on Windows 8.1.  It make's me sad that Nick decided to let the sun go down on FeedDemon, but I'm glad that it still exists and works.

Comment: RSSOwl (unchanged since 2015) is now giving me problems after having installed it on an new Windows 10 machine. Worked fine on the older Win7 PC. I'll try some of the others...